# Autocomplete does not appear for WPF controls

Tags: wpf

I'm a newbie to WPF and can't seem to understand why the editor autocomplete popup works for my business objects but not for user interface controls.  Any help would be appreciated.  For example when I type '.' after txtUserName the auto list members does not display.

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Cursor = Cursors.Wait;
        controller.Login(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Password);
        DialogResult = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
}
```

Also I continue to get these errors although my code compiles.
[image]

Comment: When you type a . the available members and properties display.  The option is called 'Auto list members'.

For example, txtUserName.Text

When you enter the . key the auto list members windows appears.  Visual Studio is not displaying the members for controls.

Comment: post your current code and a screenshot of what you mean. Also, be advised that manipulating UI elements in procedural code is generally discouraged in WPF. Use XAML and DataBinding instead.

Comment: Does your code even compile?

Comment: Absolutely.  What am I doing that is so strange?

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you able to run your app successfully ?
2. Check name of the control viz txtUserName for existance.
3. Sometimes this is normal behavior of VS. Try closing your xaml page and re-open it, or close VS altogether and re-open and check.

Comment: I updated my question with a picture.  Yes my code compiles and runs correctly.

Comment: There is no solution to this. I too have encountered such weird errors. In one of my XAML code, VS keeps on complaining that closing tag </ComboBox> is missing, but code works fine as expected. Such errors go away on their own. Try closing VS and reopen. Create another project and see if such kinda error appear again.